# Action when Enter key pressed on ANY TextField

Tags: java, forms, textfield, keylistener

Please do note that this is a different question,

I am writing a java program. I have a form with 10 JTextFields and a 'Submit' button.
How do I make the method for 'Submit' button to be called when the user presses the
enter key on **ANY** of the 10 text fields?

Should I add KeyListeners to all of the 10 or is there a more efficient way since the text fields and the button are inside a JPanel?

Comment: why do you want to invoke enter an any of the textfields?

Comment: @TimHerold May be  the submit form functionality :)

Comment: Submit.doClick(); if is about Swing

Comment: @mKorbel . but how does a program click be a listener for enter key?

Comment: add ActionListener to every JTextFields, never to use KeyListener for JTextComponents

Comment: Hmm. However I have a problem. What if none of the textFields are in focus?
can the window or jpanel wait for the enter key press?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Create an common event handler like this ,And attach it to all

**Below is a Mock code:**

```
 KeyAdapter event=  new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                //do something
            }

            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                // TODO: Do something for the keyTyped event
            }

            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                // TODO: Do something for the keyPressed event
            }
        });


txtField1.addKeyListener(event);
txtField2.addKeyListener(event);
-----
```

may be a loop also :)

Comment: @SURESH ATTA There is an extra ); without an opening )
??

Comment: @SURESHATTA  . Really Thanks for this. it works ! (avoiding the extra brace)
but is it possible to do so even if none of the fields are in focus?
Is it possible for Jpanel to listen for keypress?

Comment: Yeah that ); is an extra letter,I written code directly here :)  and coming to the panel keylistener,I did'nt try yet..but here I found a [link here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?594403-Registring-a-KeyPress-event-on-a-JPanel),But adding to paenl is not a good idea.